# Literal class with std::string only works with template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following definition is not allowed by my compiler as `std::string` has a non trivial destructor (makes sense that `teststr` can't have a trivial dtor when a member doesn't):

```
class teststr
{
private:
    std::string _m;
public:
    constexpr teststr(std::string value) : _m(value) {};

    constexpr std::string m() const { return _m; }
    void m(std::string value) { _m = value; }
};
```

However, the following equivalent (to the best of my knowledge) definition of `teststr` is allowed:

```
template<typename T>
class test
{
private:
    T _m;
public:
    constexpr test(T value) : _m(value) {};

    constexpr T m() const { return _m; }
    void m(T value) { _m = value; }
};

typedef test<std::string> teststr;
```

What is it about templating the type that makes this definition allowed?

Comment: maybe providing what compiler you are using?

Comment: g++ (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1

Comment: What happens when you instantiate the typedef?

Comment: It's not constexpr if you specify `std::string` as template argument. Try `constexpr teststr t("baba");` and it fails.

Comment: It works, and I can show with a different class that the members destructor is being called. http://ideone.com/BX4ybb

Comment: OK, but you initialized `ts` without `constexpr`. Try `constexpr teststr ts("Hello");`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr mentions requirements for non-template ctors `A non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting constexpr constructor must yield a core constant expression when appropriate arguments are provided. `, so I guess ctors of class templates may be treated differently (`T` could be type that would satisfy constexpr reuirements).

Comment: @doc, Ok, you are correct it fails as a constexpr, and it seems that could explain the difference when using a template.

Comment: Yep, also it succeeds with `int` instead of `std::string` http://ideone.com/Xd2qr6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constexpr` is more often allowed in templates because it is not generally known at template definition time whether the member satisfies the requirements of `constexpr`. When a template member is declared `constexpr`, it is determined at template instantiation time whether `constexpr` is appropriate, and if not, it is silently dropped.

Given

```
template <typename T> struct test {
  T val;
  constexpr test(T val) : val(val) { }
};
```

you can have

```
constexpr test<int> i = 3;
```

because with `T = int`, the constructor meets the requirements of `constexpr`, but you cannot have

```
constexpr test<string> s = "";
```

because *that* constructor does not meet the requirements of `constexpr`.

It is not a hard error to instantiate `test<string>` because that would severely limit the ability to use `constexpr` in templates.

From the standard (C++11):

> **7.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr]**
>
> 6 If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, that specialization is not a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor. [...]